# Spring Boot defining bean in configuration problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a project on my sparetime, on this project I have been asked to work with Spring Boot. I'm not familiar with Spring Boot from before, and I have tried searching here on stackoverflow and Google, but I can't seem to understand how the different solutions for my problem works.

First of all, this is my error message:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.project.example.controller.VerverController required a bean of type 'com.project.example.dao.VerverDao' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.project.example.dao.VerverDao' in your configuration.

After some reading, I understood that this could be because of Spring Boot don't scan this class / interface. So I tried to add ComponentScan, with no luck.

I tried to convert VerverDao from interface to class and register a bean with bean annotation. Still no luck. I tried to move the VerverDao from the dao package to the root package (the same as the Main class) and still no luck.

So if someone could please help me understand the error message, it would make my day.

This is my structure:

[image: project structure]

This is my code:

*Probably some of the annotation is wrong as well, since I'm not used to Spring Boot, in advance thanks for correcting me on the use of these*
It is also worth mentioning that I'm using Lombok as well on this project.

Main.java

```
@ComponentScan("com.gambinomafia")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class)).run(args);
        }
    }
```

Configuration.java

```
@Component
public class Configuration extends ResourceConfig {
    public Configuration() {
        register(VerverResourceImpl.class, VerverResource.class);
        register(VerverController.class);
        register(VerverDao.class);
    }
}
```

VerverResource.java

```
@Resource
@Path("verver")
public interface VerverResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/{userid}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    String getRefferingUrl(@PathParam("userid") int userid);
}
```

VerverResourceImpl.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Inject}))
public class VerverResourceImpl implements VerverResource {
    private VerverController controller;

    @Override
    public String getRefferingUrl(int userid) {
        log.info("Collection reciever url for user id: {}", userid);
        return controller.getRefferingUrl(userid);
    }
}
```

VerverController.java

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VerverController {
    private VerverDao ververDao;

    public String getRefferingUrl(int userid) {
        User user = ververDao.getUsername(userid);

        if (user.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Did not find any user with id " + userid);
        }

        return "<url-to-site>/?verv=" + user.getUsername();
    }
}
```

VerverDao.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VerverDao {
    @Value("spring.datasource.url")
    private String dbcon;

    public User getUsername(int userid) {
        Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create(dbcon);

        return jdbi.withHandle(handle -> handle.createQuery(
                "SELECT id, brukernavn FROM t_user WHERE id = :id")
                .bind("id", userid)
                .mapToBean(User.class)
                .findOnly());
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask for more information, if there is missing some information in the topic. I will try to answer as fast as possible.

Comment: Why are you mixing Spring and Jersey? Apparently you want to use Jersey and not Spring (Boot). Also the error is pretty clear your `VerverDao` isn't detected it should have a `@Repository` annotation.

Comment: Im not very familiar with Spring or Spring Boot at all. I have used Jersey in other situations and thats why I have mixed it, but I have restructured the project in according to the answer from @Cata. So trying to be more consistent using only Spring (Boot). Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First at all, you're setting a `@ComponentScan` with a wrong package in your Application class.

```
@ComponentScan("com.gambinomafia")
@SpringBootApplication
```

And, according to the picture, it has to be:

```
@ComponentScan("com.project.example")
@SpringBootApplication
```

EDIT: the use of `@ComponentScan` by @M.Deinum

Because of the Application Class is in the root package and `@SpringBootApplication` already contains `@ComponentScan`, It isn't needed to declare `@ComponentScan`.

Second, instead of use a DAO you can use Repositories. There is more information here: [Spring Boot Repositories](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

Third, to inject your objects you can use `@Autowired` over the constructor.

```
@Controller
public class VerverController
    private VerverDao ververDao;

    @Autowired
    public VerverController(VerverDao ververDao) {
        this.ververDao = ververDao;
    }
}
```

There is more information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire).

Comment: `@Autowired` is not required if you only have one constructor. The problem is that there's no stereotype annotation on `VerverDao` itself.

Comment: Thank you for a helpful feedback with good resources. This got a me past my problems, and I restructured the project using repository.

Comment: `@ComponentScan` isn't needed as that is already provided by the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. And as his application class is in the root package it isn't needed.

Comment: You're absolutely right @M.Deinum - thanks for correction.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thank you. I just edited the answer with your comment. Please, let me know if it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

Log clearly says

> VerverController required a bean of type 'com.project.example.dao.VerverDao' that could not be found.

It means there is no bean of type `com.project.example.dao.VerverDao`

Add `@Repository` on top of `VerverDao` to resolve the issue.

```
@Repository
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VerverDao {

}
```

**Note**: Ensure VerverDao is in component scanning path as per your package structure.